# php mysql query like (contains)

Tags: php, mysql, sql-like, contains

I'm trying to filter sql query by a word that is contained within a db column.

**This is working** (Please don't tell me the Having is wrong... it doesn't work with Where)

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Tutors HAVING distance < '%s' ORDER BY distance",
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius));
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

**I'd like to add something like:**

```
    $query = sprintf("SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('%s') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('%s') ) + sin( radians('%s') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Tutors HAVING distance < '%s' AND SubjectList like '%s' ORDER BY distance",
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lng),
      mysql_real_escape_string($lat),
      mysql_real_escape_string($radius),
      mysql_real_escape_string($subject));
    $result = mysql_query($query, $dbConn);
```

Comment: printf really complex your query format, so please tell what just you want to look at.

Comment: @EmCo: Wrong. you can use `having` anytime you want. The only time you HAVE to use `group by` is you're using an aggregate function

Comment: I'm wondering if the problem is that I'm using the escape_string %s and when using LIKE the string is usually %biology%

Comment: If you are comparing two numbers when you do this `distance < '%s'` that could be your problem. Try this: `distance < s`.

Comment: that didn't work either. is it possible to have another query below that uses the results of the first query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the solution that now works - thanks for everyone's help

```
$query = "SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('". addslashes($lat) ."') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('". addslashes($lng) ."') ) + sin( radians('". addslashes($lat) ."') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Tutors WHERE `SubjectList` LIKE '%". addslashes($subject) ."%' GROUP BY distance HAVING distance < '". addslashes($radius) ."'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT *,(formula) AS distance FROM Tutors WHERE SubjectList LIKE '%s' ORDER BY distance HAVING distance < '%s'
```

WHERE acts on all rows, whereas HAVING acts on aggregate functions, so you want to make sure that you have first reduced the set the aggregate formula is acting on.   This will also yield a more efficient query.

HAVING vs. WHERE is sometimes a very sticky differentiation, this link describes it very well:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/

Comment: Invalid query: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'HAVING distance < '30'' at line 1 Whole query: SELECT *, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians('46.986698') ) * cos( radians( `Lat` ) ) * cos( radians( `Long` ) - radians('-122.740799') ) + sin( radians('46.986698') ) * sin( radians( `Lat` ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM Tutors WHERE SubjectList LIKE 'biology' ORDER BY distance HAVING distance < '30'

Comment: figured it out. I had to remove the sprintf and use '%".$subject."%'